# Classification of essential singularity with Maximum

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to proof the following statements:

Let $f \colon \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < \vert z \vert < r_0 \}$ be a holomorphic function. For $0<r<r_0$ we define $M_r(f):= \operatorname{max} \{ \vert f(z) \vert : \vert z \vert = r\}$. The following statements hold true:

i) $0$ is removable iff $M_r(f)$ is bounded for $r \rightarrow 0$.

ii) $0$ is a Pole iff $M_r(f) \rightarrow \infty$ and $\exists l \in \mathbb{N}: M_r(z^lf)$ is bounded for $r \rightarrow 0$.

iii) $0$ is an essential singularity iff $\forall l \in \mathbb{N}:  M_r(z^lf)\rightarrow \infty $

I have managed to prove i) and ii). Also, because of that the direction "<=" is clear to me for iii), but I am struggling with the other one.

I would be very thankful for help.

Comment: That is also what I tried, but that did not lead to anything since 0 is also part of the boundary. Can you give me a proof please?

Comment: I started writing up a proof, and realized my argument contains a gap. Apologies. It's now not clear to me, if the hint as stated above is correct, so I'm gonna remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\Leftarrow$ implication relies on the following observation. Denote $M_r = M_r(z^l f)$, and take any sequence $\{ r_i \}$ of decreasing radii $r_i \to 0$. Then $\limsup_{i \to \infty} M_{r_i} = \limsup_{r \to 0} M_r$.

First let's see how the observation implies the $\Leftarrow$ direction. By contrapostion we need to prove that if for some $l$ we've got $M_r(z^l f) \nrightarrow \infty$, then the singularity is either a pole or removable. Since $M_r(z^l f) \nrightarrow \infty$, we can choose a decreasing sequence of radii $r_i \to 0$ such that $M_{r_i}(z^l f)$ converges to a finite limit. The observation then implies, that $\limsup_{r \to 0} M_r(z^l f)$ is equal to the same limit, hence $M_r$ is bounded, hence we find ourselves in one of the conditions i) or ii). $\square$

The proof of the observation looks as follows.

Take $0 < r_1 < r_2 < r_3$ and consider open annulus $D = \{z : r_1 < |z| < r_3 \}$.
The maximum modulus principle implies that for every closed annuli $\overline{D}$ the maximum modulus lies on the set of boundary circles. Hence the $(\star)$ estimate $M_{r_2} \leq \max \left( M_{r_1}, M_{r_3} \right)$.

To prove the observation we need to show that for any decreasing sequence $\{ r_i \}$ of real numbers converging to $0$ the equality $\limsup_{i \to \infty} M_{r_i} = \limsup_{r \to 0} M_r$ holds.
Inequality $$\limsup_{i \to \infty} M_{r_i} \leq \limsup_{r \to 0} M_r$$ is trivial (and does not require any properties of $M_r$), hence to prove the equality we need to prove the $\geq$ inequality.
Take a decreasing sequence $\{ k_i \}$ of numbers converging to $0$. We need to show that $$\limsup_{i \to \infty} M_{r_i} \geq \limsup_{i \to \infty} M_{k_i}. $$

For every $i \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $N(i) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $r_{N(i)+1} \leq k_i \leq r_{N(i)}$. Hence the $(\star)$ estimate, gives
$$M_{k_i} \leq \max \left( M_{r_{N(i)+1}}, M_{r_{N(i)}} \right). $$
Let $P(i)$ be either of numbers $\{ N(i), N(i)+1 \}$ such that $$ M_{r_{P(i)}} = \max \left( M_{r_{N(i)}}, M_{r_{N(i)+1}} \right). $$
Then for every $i$ the following inequality holds
$$ M_{r_{P(i)}} \geq M_{k_i}. $$
Hence
$$ \limsup_{i \to \infty} M_{k_i} \leq \limsup_{i \to \infty} M_{r_{P(i)}} \leq \limsup_{i \to \infty} M_{r_i}.$$

$\square$

Comment: Can I also conclude "<=" by seeing that if I assume $\forall l \in \mathbb{N}:  M_r(z^lf)\rightarrow \infty $ then by i) it cant be removable (l=0), and by ii) it cant be a pole?

Comment: I still dont quite understand "=>", I get that part with the Star Equation, but I dont understand the second paragraph. Can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: As for your first comment: yes this reasoning is OK (assuming you've got i) and ii) already). As for your second comment, I'm gonna edit my answer to add some details.

Comment: At the part where you say "for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$"... should the phrase be $\exists N(i) \in \mathbb{N}, \exists m(i) \in \mathbb{N}: r_{N(i)+m(i)}<k_i<r_{N(i)}$? Otherwise I wouldn't see why this is correct for arbitrary $(r_i), (k_i)$.

Comment: No, I believe the current phrasing is OK.
Note that $r_i$ is decreasing, so we just take two consecutive $r_i$ terms.

Comment: You are correct, sorry my bad.

Comment: Thank you! That does help.